# How to read a space delimited file into pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an input file that is like a table separated with ' '.

How do I read this space delimited file into my pandas dataframe?

I only know `read_csv` and `read_excel`.

Comment: Please share a sample input file.

Comment: If your file is a text file with fields separated by apostrophes instead of commas, you may be able to use `pd.read_csv(file, sep = "''")`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

There is an Pandas DataFrame `df`,

```
import pandas as pd

example = {'col1':[1 ,2 ,5 ,7 ,2 ,3 ,2 ,4 ,8 ,9],
        'col2':[120 ,99 ,55 ,23 ,87 ,31 ,149 ,45 ,32 ,55],
        'col3':[999 ,3741 ,8893 ,5321 ,1987 ,9299 ,573 ,4732 ,4536 ,4032]}

df = pd.DataFrame(example)
```

As follows,

```
df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
col1      int64
col2      int64
col3      int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally realize what is wrong. The first line of my file is separated by '\t' and other lines are ' ', so it makes me confused.